# Assign an IP to nic team server 2019

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2019, nic, nic-teaming

How do I assign my host an IP when all my nics have been used in a NIC Team and I've used that Teamed nic to create a virtual switch for hyper-v?

They are setup in a LACP Dynamic mode.

I've applied an ip address to the multiplexer Driver NIC but I can't reach the ip. I can reach other IP's in the subnet but not the one for the host.

I can only reach it if I assign a vlan to the NIC Team interface on the Server Manager, but then my VMs don't get traffic for their specific vlans.

Any advice?

Thank You All!